# Is there any way to just update the value from google sheets to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, webhooks

I have created a webhook and a google script to get the value from sheets and store it in the database.And with the help of triggers, i can run the script when there is a change.But while doing all the columns gets uploaded again and i have multiple entries of the same value. How do i fix this?

```
var sh1 =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
var rng =  sh1.getDataRange().getValues();
for(var i=1;i<rng.length; i++){
    var formData = {
      "timestamp": rng[i][0],
      "email":rng[i][1]
}
    var params = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'payload': formData
    }
    var getId = UrlFetchApp.fetch('webhookURL', params);
    sh1.getRange(i+1, 31).setValue(getId);
}

}
```

This is my google script. And I'm planning to copy paste the data into the google sheet and update the values in it.
And what type of trigger should I use to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only upload what was changed then you might want to look into using an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) or using `.getActiveRange()` to get the cell that was edited (you can get the column or row from there). Currently your script works as intended, it grabs all the data from the sheet and pushes it all out in a loop. This is more a design issue than an actual code problem.

Comment: So how can i fix the issue?

Comment: Do not use a `for` loop. As I said, it's a design issue. The code works as intended. Let's say you have 5 values in the spreadsheet. Any time you change any one of those values, you are intentionally asking the script to perform 5 `fetch` requests (once for each value).

Comment: And also, I did link to the event object Google Documentation, so you could look at what you can use there. `onEdit` for example can get you the old and new value so that you can generate the request just from the new value